# How to add regex for IP address in path variable of a spring boot application?

Tags: java, regex, spring-mvc, spring-boot, request-mapping

I am developing a RESTFUL server in spring-boot. For one of the rest endpoint that I am developing, the user will pass IP address as path variable. I want to validate whether the parameter passed contains valid IP address or not. One of the ways that I know is to use regex in request mapping. I have tried but it gives an error.

Request Mapping:

```
@GetMapping("/{citycode:[0-9]{3}+}/{zoneno:[0-9]{5}+}/device/info/{deviceIP:^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)}")
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The number of capturing groups in the pattern segment (((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)) does not match the number of URI template variables it defines, which can occur if capturing groups are used in a URI template regex. Use non-capturing groups instead.
```

My another concern is, regex for IP is quite long and it turns my request mapping look dirty. Is there any other way to valid IP in request mapping?

Comment: Use a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3513858/2071828)! To make things neater, use a [custom data binder](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-data-binder).